# Javascript Issues with variables which has symbol

Tags: javascript, php

I've got some issues. I have javascript function with variables, but when the description is with symbols like - "Description's" that - '. It ruins my code, how could i fix it. Here is my code:

```
onClick="javascript:insertData('
       .$currentTasken.', \''.$currentDate.'\', '
       .$currentUser.', \''.$currentSummary.'\', '
       .$currentAsPercent.', \''.$currentDescription.'\');"
```

I used  `\''.$currentSummary.'\'` like this, but still having some issues if that text has this symbol ' . I havent tried other but I think it would be the same. Help.

Comment: maybe something like this: `onClick="javascript:insertData(\"{$currentTasken}, {$currentDate}, {$currentUser} {$currentSummary}, {$currentAsPercent}, {$currentDescription}\")";`

Comment: But now its `<img src="./images/icons/tick.png" alt="Check" onclick="javascript:insertData(\" {$currenttasken},="" {$currentdate},="" {$currentuser}="" {$currentsummary},="" {$currentaspercent},="" {$currentdescription}\")";="" height="12" width="12" border="0">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the snippet you show in your post is within a PHP section. In that case `onClick` should really be `$onclick` (i. e. a valid PHP variable name). Otherwise you could do the whole thing inside a html section.

```
<?PHP
// first mask all dangerous "'" as "\\'"  within the variables:
foreach (array('currentTasken','currentDate','currentUser','currentSummary',
               'currentAsPercent','currentDescription') as $v ) 
            $$v=str_replace("'","\\'",$$v);
?>

<!-- some type of html tag ... whatever it might be in your case -->
<input type="button" 
 onClick="javascript:insertData<?PHP echo
   "('$currentTasken','$currentDate','$currentUser','$currentSummary',"
   ."'$currentAsPercent','$currentDescription')"; ?> >
```

In PHP strings within `"` will allow for variables to be evaluated inside. You don't have to concatenate the string with `.`s.

Comment: Thanx used str_replace :)